# How can I disable kendodatetimepicker on button click?

Tags: jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to disable my kendodatetimepicker on button click. I am new to kendo and jQuery. Please help me.

```
 $("#myButtom").click(function(){
       //code for disable here.
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:-

```
 $("#myButtom").on("click",function(){
     $('#mydatepicker').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(false);
 });
```

Comment: You can improve this line using the .on method $("#myButton").on("click", function () { ... });